# IGBT half bridge inverter not giving correct output

Tags: inverter, gate-driving, igbt

I am making a half-bridge square wave inverter using IGBTs ([GW20NC60VD](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stgw20nc60vd.pdf)) and gate driver [HCPL 3120](https://datasheet.octopart.com/HCPL-3120-500E-Avago-datasheet-8326769.pdf). The input signal for the gate driver IC is taken from an Arduino. The signal is of 60KHz frequency. A 0.1uF capacitor is connected between pin 5 and 8 of IC. The output gate signal is taken from pin 6/7 with a 5-ohm gate resistor attached in series.
[image]
[image]
15V isolated supply is given to both ICs. A load resistor is connected between the emitter of high side IGBT and the emitter of Low side IGBT. The output is taken across the load resistor which is shown below. A 31 V signal is given across the half-bridge which is to be inverted.
[image]
The output signal instead of having a square wave of 50% duty cycle is the signal as shown. The signal also has spikes. Kindly if anybody can tell what is wrong.

Comment: Include links to the relevant datasheets, like I did for the GW20NC60VD. The HCPL 3120 appears not to be a gate driver but an opto-coupler? Are the emitter-gate voltages of the IGBTs what you expect? Don't connect the scope's ground to the emitter of the top IGBT, instead use **two** probes and subtract their signals.

Comment: 2.5 Amp Output Current IGBT Gate Drive Optocoupler

Comment: BOth 15V supplies are isolated from each other?  Low side switch is not working.  Keep probe ground wires short << 2cm for ring suppression or use tip and ring

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 yes both supplies are isolated. How to make the low side switch working. Didn't get your suggestion. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie HCPL 3120 is an optocoupler based gate driver. Yes, the gate voltage is as expected for the top IGBT but not for the bottom IGBT. I have not connected the scope ground to the emitter of the top IGBT. I have attached the scope ground to the emitter of the bottom IGBT across the load resistor. How to subtract the signal didn't get that.

Comment: Measure and markup schematic with all voltages for low side. Earth ground both probes and measure with ch A-B. Calibrate for no noise when both on a dynamic pulse (null difference with probe cal.) you may need a cap to supply gnd from earth gnd.